# Vue JS autosizing textarea on load

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Learning Vue so this may be a basic question. I have a component that renders a textarea input:

```
<textarea
    v-if="$attrs.type === 'textarea'"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :value="value"
    @input="inputChange"
    :class="[
        error ? 'text-red-500' : 'text-gray-600',
        textareaAutoResized ? 'h-32' : '',
        inputClass,
    ]"
></textarea>
```

My `inputChange` method works well:

```
methods: {
    inputChange(evt) {
        let value = evt.target.value
        this.$emit('input', value)

        if (this.$attrs.type === 'textarea' && this.textareaAutoResized) {
            evt.target.style.height = "auto";
            let newHeight = evt.target.scrollHeight;
            evt.target.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;
        }

    },
},
```

But I cannot get the textarea to auto size on page load based on initial content. How do I access the element on mounted? Thanks!

```
    mounted() {
        if (this.$attrs.type === 'textarea' && this.textareaAutoResized) {
            this.$el.style.height = "auto";
            let newHeight = this.$el.scrollHeight;
            this.$el.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$ref` on your `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea
    ref="textarea"
    v-if="$attrs.type === 'textarea'"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :value="value"
    @input="inputChange"
    :class="[
        error ? 'text-red-500' : 'text-gray-600',
        textareaAutoResized ? 'h-32' : '',
        inputClass,
    ]"
></textarea>
```

and get it on mounted:

```
mounted() {
    if (this.$attrs.type === 'textarea' && this.textareaAutoResized) {
        this.$refs.textarea.style.height = "auto";
        let newHeight = this.$refs.textarea.scrollHeight;
        this.$refs.textarea.style.height = `${newHeight}px`;
    }
},
```

Comment: As many other posts demonstrate, using $ref on mounted sometimes works, sometimes not. Didn't work for me in this example. I think the questioner is making a good point: Isn't there an event handler for mounted (similar to the standard onload), so that his inputChange could be used on both?